# MSBuild WebDeploy error when deploying to a virtual directory

Tags: tfs

I'm a newbie to TFS Deployment, I'm facing a strange issue when I try to deploy to a website in the form ABC\SomeVirtual

The error code is

Deployment on one or more machines failed. System.Exception: ERROR ( message:Can not set attribute "name" to value "ABC\SomeVirtual".. Reason: Invalid site name  . )

[image]

If I put a site name without '\' it works...

I've tried either to put in the form ABC/SomeVirtual but nothing works... any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using TFS 2015,  in TFS 2015 `IIS Web App Management` task can only create website name, it cannot create the virtual application name. So you cannot use  '`\`' or  '`/`' to create the virtual application name using this task.

Generally, if the website is not exist, then you can use `IIS Web App Management` task to create the website first, then use `IIS Web App Deployment` task to deploy to the website or virtual Application like `Site/Application`...

If the parent website already exist, then you can directly use `IIS Web App Deployment` task to deploy the virtual application, `IIS Web App Management` task is not necessary.

For example:

To create an application named `Site/Application` (`Test0906/0928` in below sample), you need to make sure the `Site` (`Test0926` in below sample) already exist there... Reference below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @andy, disabling the IIS Web App Management it worked... do you know if using TFS 2018 I can have both enabled? I ask you since for normal deployment (I mean not on a web server instance, it works), but what if I have a new Server and I want to set it up?